# Should this question be closed or edited?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

This is the question:

[What did Jesus say about the end times?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31622/what-did-jesus-say-about-the-end-times)

Here's the problem I have with it. It is essentially, "What does the Bible say about x?" [Which the community has decided is essentially primarily opinion based](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/biblical-basis-vs-what-the-bible-says-about-a-subject). This shows in [that question's most recent answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/39018/3961). I can't downvote that answer in all earnestness because it does answer the question and within the frame of that question. To the answerer, this is what Jesus has said about the topic. This, of course, is exactly why questions of this form should be closed or edited.

Further explanation: "What Jesus said" is not limited to the Gospels. Jesus also speaks in Revelation. The SDA and JW believe that Michael is Jesus. An answer I read recently argued that Melchizedek was Jesus. One of the answers on the post in question quotes 1 Cor. and says "here's what Jesus said through Paul". In fact, any country bumpkin has a valid opinion to answer this question from anything in the Bible as something Jesus said, because He is God after all. If the question intends to limit to the Gospels, then it should say so (as in, it needs an edit). I guess I'm fine with that scope limiting.

Does the community agree? If yes, should we see an edit or just a close vote?

---

[This question was apparently mentioned before in meta.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/the-fine-line-between-good-and-poor-question) I do not think *this* question is a duplicate of that because that question is actually about a different main site question and only references the main site question I'm asking about as an example.

Comment: Good question; I'm not sure. And [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/25071/9289) is similar enough that I don't think it warrants a separate meta post (go ahead and disagree with this poor soul if you want).

Comment: possible duplicate of [The fine line between good and poor question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3923/the-fine-line-between-good-and-poor-question)

Answer (score -4):

The OP didn't ask `"What does the Bible say about 'X'?"` The OP asked `"What did **Jesus** say about 'X'?"` The latter is much more specific and limited in scope to just the Gospels.

So in conclusion, there's no need for an edit or a close vote.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited this down to only the relevant information.  I don't think it's appropriate to use Meta to tell people, personally, what you think of their voting habits, but I do agree that this is more limited in scope.  I do wish I'd thought of a way to edit this and retain the Rogers pic, however.

Comment: "What Jesus said" is not limited to the Gospels. Jesus also speaks in Revelation. The SDA and JW believe that Michael *is* Jesus. An answer I read recently argued that Melchizedek was Jesus. One of the answers on the post in question quotes 1 Cor. and says "here's what Jesus said through Paul". In fact, any country bumpkin has a valid opinion to answer this question from anything in the Bible as something Jesus said, because He is God after all. If the question intends to limit to the Gospels, then it should say so (as in, it needs an edit). I guess I'm fine with that scope limiting.

Comment: Seems like you're on meta telling people to calm down and be more lax about enforcement a lot, and get downvoted just as much. Perhaps you're in the minority?